# Remove everything after the last occurrence of selected character in the first line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say we have a variable that contains multiple lines of text containing full file names, such as

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\Resource\CMap\Adobe-Japan2-0
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\poppler\cMap\Adobe-Japan2\Adobe-Japan2-0
```

...and this multi-line text is assigned to the variable `var`.

In Windows/DOS **command prompt** (not PowerShell), without a use of any external tools, how can I remove everything after the last occurrence of the character `\` in the first line, i.e. for the above example to get only

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\Resource\CMap\
```

---

Here is a part of the code I use:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%x in ('copy /z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%x"

(set LF=^
%==%
)

set TAB=    "
set "TAB=%TAB:"=%

net session >nul 2>&1
if !errorLevel! NEQ 0 (
  echo ERROR: Use "Run as administrator" to execute this file.!LF!
  pause
  exit /b 1
)

<nul set/p"=Analyzing... "

set "nil= "
for /l %%i in (2,1,80) do call set "nil=%%nil%%%nil%"

set "STDOUT="
set "STDERR="

for /f "delims=" %%E in ('
  2^>^&1 ^(^
    for /f "delims=" %%O in ^('^
      where /R "%programfiles%" "*adobe*.*"
      ^^^^^^^| findstr /i /n /r "japan2"^ 
    '^) do @^(^
      echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^
    ^)^
  ^) ^| findstr /n /r "^"
') do (
  set "LINE=%%E"
  set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
  if "!LINE:~,1!" == "|" (
    set "STDOUT=!STDOUT!!LINE:*:=!!LF!"
  ) else (
    set "STDERR=!STDERR!!LINE!!LF!"
  )
)
```

Comment: Woah! You said no external tools, but your code uses `net.exe`, `where.exe`, and `findstr.exe`. Those are not in cmd.exe.

Comment: @lit - They are part of standard Windows 10 distribution, therefore I don't consider them to be **external** tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code created trailing whitespace to each path it found. I modified the code to get rid of this.
The paths had to be double quote as they contain whitespace in the path as well. The variable `!STDOUT!` with therefore have the following format:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\Resource\CMap\Adobe-Japan2-0"
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\poppler\cMap\Adobe-Japan2\Adobe-Japan2-0"
```

You mentioned that this is only part of the code, so you need to make sure that everything else works as expected.
**Note** however that you need to copy this part of the code *"exactly"* as is as I have amended a few parts of it, if you don't, it will not work as expected.

Lastly, I have to add. I am not sure of the reason this code was designed like this, I cannot see any specific reason, based on the current scenario.
This code is a bit of an overkill for now, unless you can provide a specific reason. I do not see any reason why the variable cannot be `set` without the line feeds.

Anyway, here it is:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%x in ('copy /z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%x"

(set LF=^
%==%
)

set TAB=    "
set "TAB=%TAB:"=%

net session >nul 2>&1
if !errorLevel! NEQ 0 (
  echo ERROR: Use "Run as administrator" to execute this file.!LF!
  pause
  exit /b 1
)

<nul set/p"=Analyzing... "
echo(

set "nil= "
for /l %%i in (2,1,80) do call set "nil=%%nil%%%nil%"

set "STDOUT="
set "STDERR="

for /f "delims=" %%E in ('
  2^>^&1 ^(^
    for /f "delims=" %%O in ^('^
      where /R "%programfiles%" "*adobe*.*"
      ^^^^^^^| findstr /i /n /r "japan2"^ 
    '^) do @^(^
      echo ^^^^^^^|%%O^
    ^)^
  ^) ^| findstr /n /r "^"
') do (
  set "LINE=%%E"
  set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
  set "LINE=!LINE:  =!"
  if "!LINE:~,1!" == "|" (
    set STDOUT=!STDOUT!"!LINE:*:=!"!LF!
  ) else (
    set "STDERR=!STDERR!!LINE!!LF!"
  )
)
for %%i in (!STDOUT!) do set "dir=%%~dpi" & goto cont:
:cont
echo !dir!
```

The main changes in the code you provided are here:

```
  set "LINE=!LINE:  =!"   :: Removed the two trailing whitespaces
  if "!LINE:~,1!" == "|" (               
  set STDOUT=!STDOUT!"!LINE:*:=!"!LF! :: Double quote the line so we can format them correctly.
```

This will allow proper usage of the strings in a list form.

Then, my code added. This sets a `pth` variable using drive and path to file. We then strip the trailing `\` to allow the next `%%~dpa` to assign the drive and path to the point where you wanted it.

```
for %%i in (!STDOUT!) do set "dir=%%~dpi" & goto cont:
:cont
echo !dir!
```

The result will then be:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\Resource\CMap\
```

Finally, if you want to see that my part of the code does in fact remove the parts from path as you wanted, you can do this in my code section:

```
for %%i in (!STDOUT!) do (
   echo %%~dpi
)
```

Or if you want to set each of them to a `dir[n]` to resemble an array, then place this in my code section:

```
set _n=1
for %%i in (!STDOUT!) do (
   set "dir[!_n!]=%%~dpi"
   set /a _n+=1
)
for /l %%n in (0,1,!_n!) do echo(!dir[%%n]!
set dir
```